# Can't save in GTA V!

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I did the mission where you kill the last 3 O'Neills, missions after that and I saved. But whenever I play the game, it loads back to the mission with the last 3 O'Neills! Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: The game might be loading the last autosave, try manually loading your save.

Answer (score 1):

After defeating the o'Neil brothers, manually save the game by going on to your **phone**, and hitting the **Quick Save** option. **Make sure the loading animation finishes** before you switch off your console.